# Resolve jquery deferred object with another deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

How to resolve one Deffered object with resolve state of another.
Simple example and simple explanation please (saw a lot of difficult ones).

How I can resolve `result` promise with a `foo()`, without `.done(..)` and `.fail(..)`?

```js
var result = $.Deferred();

/**
 * @returns {Deferred}
 */
var foo = function() {
  // ... something that returns deferred object at random moment of time
};

foo()
  .done(function(){result.resolve()})
  .fail(function(){result.reject()})
;

setTimeout(function() {
    result.reject();
}, 50);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Result is:', result.state());
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This smells of [the deferred anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: it's more complex. `foo` function can be not allowed for modify, and `result` can be resolved in many other ways. But if `foo` has been resolved the very first, `result` should have that resolution of the `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Deferred object `def` is superfluous (see the links given by Benajmin Gruenbaum why it's actually dangerous [silent fails]). Resolve/reject the result object:

```js
var result = $.Deferred();
var foo = function() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? result.resolve() : result.reject();
};

setTimeout(function(){
    document.write('Result is:', result.state());
}, 500);

foo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is called [the deferred anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for shedding light on an aspect of the code that was outside my focus. Answer adjusted.

Comment: Resolving a `result` deferred that is defined outside of your `foo` function is actually even worse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function passed in [`$.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and resolve/reject deferred from inside:

```js
var result = $.Deferred(function() {
    Math.random() > 0.5 ? this.resolve() : this.reject();
});

setTimeout(function(){
    document.write('Result is: ' + result.state());
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If we're being clever: `var result = $.Deferred()[Math.random() > 0.5 ? "resolve" : "reject"]()`